# Sharepoint 2010 replication between multiple offices

Tags: sharepoint, replication, sharepoint-2010, wide-area-network

Does Sharepoint 2010 address geo replication?  My searches kept coming up with a third party solution but I'd rather stick to a built in option if it's available.  I have multiple offices over 4.5 and 1.5 mbps WAN connections who access sharepoint and I want it to be LAN like speed with file locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is supported in the way you are talking about. (With a full SharePoint and SQL Server at each office that are all mirrors of each other.) 2010 does have some increased functionality for branch office scenarios over 2007 though. Check out this blog post:

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/modonovan/archive/2009/10/22/does-sharepoint-2010-help-out-in-south-africa-with-our-expensive-and-constrained-wan-connections.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/modonovan/does-sharepoint-2010-help-out-in-south-africa-with-our-expensive-and-constrained-wan-connections)

Which goes into some details - I think especially check out the BranchCache scenario.